# Micronaut metrics to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, metrics, micronaut

I am looking for an example how on how to send Micronaut's metric to elastic search, it does not look like it is supported out of the box ?

Thank you, kindly 
  Luis Oscar Trigueiros

Comment: What about this: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-elasticsearch + https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-elasticsearch/latest/guide/index.html?

Comment: I belive this allows to connect to elastic to send documents but I was hoping to find a metrics register implementation like described in https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-micrometer/1.1.x/guide/index.html

Comment: Hmmm, maybe something could be done using the [Metricbeat prometheus module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-prometheus.html) which can connect to prometheus exporters (like the one for Micronaut you just linked)...

Comment: Is this module expecting to connect to Prometheus, or is it running as a proxy that I can send metrics using prometheus protocol and it will send them to elastic ?

Comment: It connects to Prometheus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micronaut 1.2.0 will include support for Elastic as a backend for the metrics using Micrometer.
From https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#_micronaut_micrometer_1_2_update

> Meter registry support for AppOptics, Azure Monitor, Datadog, Dynatrace, Elastic, Ganglia, Humio, Influx, Jmx, Kairos, New Relic, SignalFX, Stackdriver and Wavefront

Keep in mind that this is not included in `1.2.0.RC1` but it will be available in `1.2.0.RC2`.